# Set multiple key-value pairs as a value to a key in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to form an array consisting of an object whose value is, in turn, a group of key-value pair of objects from an array of objects. Basically, I'm trying to assign a group of objects in an array (from a Request JSON) as a value to an object key (parentKey) in another array. Kindly help me out with the following:

**Source - Array of objects:**

```
{
  "Array": [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Result - Array with an object whose value is a group of key-value pair of objects:**

```
{
  "Array":[{
    "parentKey": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
        }
    },{
    "parentKey": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
        }
    },{
    "parentKey": {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: `an array consisting of an object whose value is, in turn, a group of key-value pair of objects from an array of objects` these is not how someone should ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the `Array` property of the object and push the `parentKey` object in a new array. And finally you can set that array to a new object with property `Array`.

```js
var input = {
  "Array":[{
    "parentKey": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
     }
    },
    {
     "parentKey": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
     }
    },
    {
    "parentKey": {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
     }
  }]
}

var arr = [];

input.Array.forEach((obj)=>{
  arr.push(obj.parentKey);
});
var output = {
  "Array" : arr
};

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this.

```js
let given={
      "Array":[{
        "parentKey": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
            }
        },{
        "parentKey": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
            }
        },{
        "parentKey": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
            }
        }]
    }

    let result={
      "Array":[]
    }

    given.Array.forEach((subArr, i)=>{
      result.Array.push(subArr.parentKey)
    })

    console.log(result)
```

And the other way around it is like this:

```js
let given=
{
  "Array": [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2",
      "key3": "value3"
    }
  ]
}


let result={
  "Array":[]
}

given.Array.forEach((subArr, i)=>{
  result.Array.push({"parentKey":subArr})
})

console.log(result)
```